# RecyclerView only show the first array index

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to display all contact that i get from api and show it using recyclerview. But when i want to run the code it show only one contact, actually it has 2 contacts on array.

Recyclerview adapter

```
    package com.example.ilham.dompettebal;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class contactRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<contactRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;


    contactRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<String> data)
    {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String teman = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(teman);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTeman);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

mainactivity that include get data from server and recyclerview

```
package com.example.ilham.dompettebal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONObjectRequestListener;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements contactRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    contactRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView username;
    public String tokenUser;
    public JSONObject namaTeman;
    public JSONArray friends;
    private TextView usernameFriends;
    ArrayList<String> usernameFriendsProfile = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tokenUser= getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
        Log.d(TAG, "tokenmainactivity" + tokenUser); //untuk log pada onerror
        Log.d(TAG, "tokenhalamanselanjutnya " + tokenUser);
        username = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.user);
        usernameFriends = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameTeman);
    initData();



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void initData() {
        //get user
        AndroidNetworking.get("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users")
                .addHeaders("Authorization","Bearer "+tokenUser)
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response); //untuk log pada onresponse
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                            String usernameAkun = obj.getString("username");
                            username.setText(usernameAkun);
                            Log.d(TAG, "namaprofil : " + username);
                            JSONArray friends = obj.getJSONArray("friends");

                            for (int i=0;i<friends.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject objek = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                                usernameFriendsProfile.add(objek.getString("username"));
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "usernametemendidalem : " + usernameFriendsProfile);
//                            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.contact_recyclerview,R.id.usernameTeman,usernameFriendsProfile);
//                            teman.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.teman);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                            adapter = new contactRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, usernameFriendsProfile);
                            adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError: Failed" + error); //untuk log pada onerror
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

The values of usernameFriendsProfile is [falah, ilham] but on the display it only shows the first index like this
The contact interface -

[image: the contact interface]

this is the active_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addFriendButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchButton"
        android:src="@drawable/add_friend"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/settingButton"
        android:src="@drawable/search"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/setting"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/myprofile"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Username" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Teman"
        android:layout_below="@id/myprofile"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        />
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/contact"
       android:id="@+id/teman"
       />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is on contact recycleview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usernameTeman"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Username" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: the recyclerview only show  one contact but actually there are two contacts on array

Comment: Can you please attach your layout codes - for activity_main.xml, and contact_recyclerview

Comment: yes i already add it

Answer (score 0):

**RecyclerView**

**Definition:**

> If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on
>   large data sets (or data that frequently changes), you should use
>   RecyclerView as described on this page.

The most common issue with the UI not showing all the elements could be:

The item layout for each row that you are using here, in this case, is

**R.layout.contact_recyclerview** I suggest you make the     android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the XML file.